# Get information from Firebase Realtime Database with Firebase Admin SDK

Tags: java, firebase, firebase-realtime-database

I'm trying to get some information from Firebase Real-time database without success. I don't know what I'm doing wrong. I also tried the doc's example and they didn't work. Here's my code and my firebase db structue:

[image: Database structure]

Topics.java:

```
public class Topics {

 private String name;

 public Topics() {

 }

 public Topics(String name) {
    this.name = name;
 }

 public String getName() {
    return name;
 }

 public void setName(String name) {
    this.name = name;
 }

}
```

Main.java

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    FileInputStream serviceAccount;
    FirebaseOptions options = null;
    try {
        serviceAccount = new FileInputStream(".//...");
        options = new FirebaseOptions.Builder()
                .setCredentials(GoogleCredentials.fromStream(serviceAccount))
                .setDatabaseUrl("...")
                .build();

    } catch (FileNotFoundException e) {
        // TODO Auto-generated catch block
        e.printStackTrace();
    } catch(IOException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }

    FirebaseApp.initializeApp(options);
    String topics = getDatafromFirebase();

    System.out.println("Everything right!");
}

private static String getDatafromFirebase() {
    CountDownLatch done = new CountDownLatch(1);
    StringBuilder b = new StringBuilder();
    DatabaseReference dbRef = FirebaseDatabase.getInstance()
            .getReference();

    dbRef.child("topics").addValueEventListener(new ValueEventListener() {
        @Override
        public void onDataChange(DataSnapshot snapshot) {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub
            if(snapshot.exists()) {
                for(DataSnapshot s:snapshot.getChildren()) {
                    Topics t = s.getValue(Topics.class);
                    b.append(t.getName());
                    b.append(" ");
                    done.countDown();
                }
            }
            else {
                b.append("No existe ");
                done.countDown();
            }

        }

        @Override
        public void onCancelled(DatabaseError error) {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub
            b.append("Error: "+error.getDetails());
            done.countDown();
        }
        });
    try {
        done.await();
    } catch (InterruptedException e) {
        // TODO Auto-generated catch block
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
    return b.toString();
}
```

I have wait for the `CountDownLatch` for `5+` minutes, which I think is enough time for it to trigger. Also, important note: I have successfully sent message through firebase cloud messaging, so I don't think that it is a problem with the credentials.

Comment: At first glance the code looks fine to me. If you put a breakpoint in `onDataChange`, does it get triggered?

Comment: @FrankvanPuffelen put breakpoints in both  `onDataChange` and `onCancelled`. They don't get triggered.

Comment: The only reason that happens is if the client never gets an answer from the server. That can happen (in my experience) because the client doesn't have an internet connection, or because the client exits before the data comes back from the server.

Comment: Another reason could be that the credentials are not well set. Check in firebase console if the SHA key of your computer is correct. When you said that you use FirebaseCloudMessaging, you mean in this code?

Comment: @Juanje How can I check the SHA Key in firebase and my computer? Not with the code that It's in my question. I wrote a method to send a notification to my app with the same Firebase initialization (same credentials, same database-url,etc).

Comment: You should login as a client and give you access as an admin from your database rules.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I ran your code against my database with the same db structure and I can for sure say that I am ableto get information from the database.

`onDataChange` breakpoint not triggering only happens if I remove the `topics` subtree entirely. ie. in  your case an empty database.

I suspect either your database url or Private Key JSON.

### Follow the below Instruction for a new private key

1. In the console, click the **gear icon** on the left, and the **Service Accounts** Tab
   [Refer](https://i.stack.imgur.com/CbReE.png)
2. Take a note of **databaseUrl** and click on **Generate New Private Key**, save it.
   [Refer](https://i.stack.imgur.com/LhXwx.png)

## Here is the working code for example

```
package fireb;

import java.io.FileInputStream;
import java.io.FileNotFoundException;
import java.io.IOException;
import java.util.concurrent.CountDownLatch;

import com.google.auth.oauth2.GoogleCredentials;
import com.google.firebase.FirebaseApp;
import com.google.firebase.FirebaseOptions;
import com.google.firebase.database.DataSnapshot;
import com.google.firebase.database.DatabaseError;
import com.google.firebase.database.DatabaseReference;
import com.google.firebase.database.FirebaseDatabase;
import com.google.firebase.database.ValueEventListener;


public class Fireb {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        FileInputStream serviceAccount;
        FirebaseOptions options = null;
        try {
            serviceAccount = new FileInputStream("C:\\key\\testapp-f0fe2-firebase-adminsdk-4po4a-5ce6c60b81.json");
            options = new FirebaseOptions.Builder()
                    .setCredentials(GoogleCredentials.fromStream(serviceAccount))
                    .setDatabaseUrl("https://testapp-f0fe2.firebaseio.com")
                    .build();

        } catch (FileNotFoundException e) {
            // TODO Auto-generated catch block
            e.printStackTrace();
        } catch(IOException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }

        FirebaseApp.initializeApp(options);
        String topics = getDatafromFirebase();
        System.out.println(topics);
        System.out.println("Everything right!");
    }

    private static String getDatafromFirebase() {
        CountDownLatch done = new CountDownLatch(1);
        StringBuilder b = new StringBuilder();
        DatabaseReference dbRef = FirebaseDatabase.getInstance()
                .getReference();

        dbRef.child("topics").addValueEventListener(new ValueEventListener() {
            @Override
            public void onDataChange(DataSnapshot snapshot) {
                // TODO Auto-generated method stub
                if(snapshot.exists()) {
                    for(DataSnapshot s:snapshot.getChildren()) {
                        Topics t = s.getValue(Topics.class);
                        b.append(t.getName());
                        b.append(" ");
                    }
                    done.countDown();
                }
                else {
                    b.append("No existe ");
                    done.countDown();
                }

            }

            @Override
            public void onCancelled(DatabaseError error) {
                // TODO Auto-generated method stub
                b.append("Error: "+error.getDetails());
                done.countDown();
            }
            });
        try {
            done.await();
        } catch (InterruptedException e) {
            // TODO Auto-generated catch block
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
        return b.toString();
    }
}
```

Comment: This and deleting all items from database and then recreating then again made the code work!

Answer (score 0):

According to the documentation available [here](https://firebase.google.com/docs/database/admin/start).

> Before you can access the Firebase Realtime Database from a server using the Firebase Admin SDK, you must authenticate your server with Firebase. When you authenticate a server, rather than sign in with a user account's credentials as you would in a client app, you authenticate with a service account which identifies your server to Firebase.

If you are not running your code on server, you may authenticate as a client instead as described [here](https://firebase.google.com/docs/database/web/start).

Hope this helps.